# List available SQL Servers on network

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display a list of available SQL serves into a listbox using the following code:

```
DataTable dt = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(string.Concat(dr["ServerName"], "\\", dr["InstanceName"]));
}
```

However, this adds nothing to the listBox. While debugging, I found that dt.Rows.Cout is actually equal to zero, even though I have a server on my computer through SQLEXPRESS 2010. Any ideas?

Ok Thank you all for your help. The following code worked best for me:

```
        ManagedComputer mc = new ManagedComputer();
        mc.ConnectionSettings.ProviderArchitecture = ProviderArchitecture.Use64bit;
        foreach (ServerInstance si in mc.ServerInstances)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(Environment.MachineName + "\\" + si.Name);
        }
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx) says "Retrieves a DataTable containing information about all visible SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005 instances."

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Retrieves a DataTable containing information about all visible **SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005 instances**.

Try using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx), especially the [`SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoapplication.enumavailablesqlservers.aspx) method

Comment: @twn You have posted a comment about my answer about 51 min ago and now you have removed it. Since I wasn't able to answer you immediately, I will do it now. Yeah, our answers is very similar. However as you will notice as the time passes our time difference in the initial post was less than a half of minute. Later Roger asked how could solve his problem. I did a little research and I found the link that I have included in my answer. When I got back to reedit my post, you had for a couple of minutes refered to to this method. This doesn't mean in any way that I copied/pasted your answer.

Comment: @twn In no way I would downvote a correct answer as your answer is, despite the fact that you have downvoted mine, because you believe I copied/pasted your answer. I leave the judgement to the readers of our answers.

Comment: @Christos No, you didn't copy/paste from my answer but your answer is redundant to what I've already posted.

Answer (score -1):

The following method

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
```

> Retrieves a DataTable containing information about all visible SQL
>   Server 2000 or SQL Server 2005 instances.

as it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx).

So I assume that you haven't neither a 2000 nor a 2005 sql server instance to your network. How can you overcome this?

You could use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms210334.aspx). I found this approach [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/get-all-instances-of-sql-server-in-C-Sharp/).

Initially you have to add a reference to your project of the dll, `Microsoft.SqlServer.smo.dll`, that contains the type you will use:

The paths are the following:

- For 64-bit Windows 7: [Your drive]:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
- For 32-bit Windows 7: [Your drive]:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Then you could get that you want as below:

```
DataTable dataTable = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but althrough this answer the question, it's not very helpful. I guess the OP also wants to know how they can get a list of other SQL Server instances.

Comment: Oh Thank you! Do you know of code to retrieve info about SQL Server 2012 and below?

Comment: @Roger you welcome dude. I will try to make a search and I will back asap.

Comment: @Roger, please have a look at my updated post and please let me know if that suits your case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Roger you welcome dude ! If you notice any problem, please let me know. Thanks.